# How is the index calculated in C code "*inputData ^ inputData[decoder - (char*)data];"

Tags: c

There is some C code which is performing some basic decryption sequence, the relevant code below:

```
char key4;
BYTE* data; // a 128 item char array is passed to this pointer
char decoderKey[44] = { -20, 100, -50, -70, 40, etc }
char decoder[44]; 
memcpy(decoder, decoderKey, 40);
decoder[40] = decoderKey[40];
char key1 = decoder[36] ^ data[36];
char key3 = decoder[37] ^ data[37];
char* inputData = (char*)data;

for (int counter = 0; counter < cbSize; counter++, ++inputData)
{
    key4 = *inputData ^ inputData[decoder - (char*)data];
    *inputData = key4;
    if (!(counter % 4)) *inputData = key1 ^ key4;
    if ((counter % 4) == 1) *inputData ^= key3;
}
```

I am trying to workout how to replicate similar code in C# to calculate the value for key4. To do this I need to understand how to calculate the input for `inputData[decoder - (char*)data]`

As *inputData is incremented, counter also contains the offset i.e. inputData[counter] would refer to the current value at inputData in the loop. However I have no idea what the equivalent (decoder-char*)data would be. The data pointer is never moved.
To try and work this out I tried calculating the position separately:

```
int i = (decoder - (char*)data);
char keyTest = inputData[counter] ^ inputData[i];
```

This gets the right value into keyTest, but i references is a number not in the array, i.e. in this case the first time it executes i = -436, and inputData is a 128 byte array.

I further tested with this code which retrieved same correct value for first iteration of loop into keyTest:

```
char item = inputData[-436];
char keyTest = inputData[counter] ^ item;
```

Compiler is the one included with Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 and generates the following code for the negative array reference:

```
; 34   :         char item = inputData[-436];

  0010a b8 01 00 00 00           mov     eax, 1
  0010f 69 c8 4c fe ff  ff       imul    ecx, eax, -436
  00115 8b 55 c0                 mov     edx, DWORD PTR _inputData$[ebp]
  00118 8a 04 0a                 mov     al, BYTE PTR [edx+ecx]
  0011b 88 85 3f ff ff  ff       mov     BYTE PTR _item$2[ebp], al
```

I then tried this code:

```
char* x = decoder;
char* y = (char*)data;
int i = x - y;
    
key4 = *inputData ^ inputData[i];
printf("i = %i key4 = %i x = %p y = %p inputData = %p data = %p decoder = %p\r\n", i, key4,x,y,inputData,data,decoder);
```

Which outputs the following:

```
i = -300 key4 = -79 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF774 data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = 58 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF775 data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = 99 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF776 data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = 0 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF777 data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = -77 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF778 data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = 58 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF779 data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = 101 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF77A data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = 0 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF77B data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = -68 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF77C data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = 58 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF77D data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = 101 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF77E data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = 0 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF77F data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = -94 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF780 data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = 58 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF781 data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = 97 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF782 data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = 0 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF783 data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = -92 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF784 data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = 58 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF785 data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = 111 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF786 data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = 0 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF787 data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = -94 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF788 data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = 58 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF789 data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = 33 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF78A data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = 0 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF78B data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = -15 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF78C data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = 58 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF78D data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = 0 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF78E data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = 0 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF78F data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = -48 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF790 data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = 58 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF791 data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = 0 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF792 data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = 0 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF793 data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = -48 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF794 data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = 58 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF795 data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = 0 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF796 data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = 0 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF797 data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = -48 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF798 data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = 58 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF799 data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = 0 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF79A data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
i = -300 key4 = 0 x = 00FDF648 y = 00FDF774 inputData = 00FDF79B data = 00FDF774 decoder = 00FDF648
```

Comment: Instead of using char (is 16 bit in c#) use byte (8 bit).

Comment: i'm using byte in c# but don't understand how this pointer operation maps to what index in the array i.e. decoder - (char*)data

Comment: It's often better to understand the code and then try to replicate the same functionality rather than just translating.

Comment: I agree I don’t understand it at this point

Comment: `decoder - (char*)data` is only well defined when `data` points to an element of `decoder` or to just past its final element. The pointer difference will be between -44 and 0 inclusive in that case. It seems that the original code is wrong.

Comment: Change the pointer to an index.  The code posted isn't enough to give an answer.  You would need something like : key4 = inputData[i] ^ inputData[decoder - data[j]];  I would need where the pointers are incrementing like data++